# PHP : Split a comma delimited & special symbol string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, codeigniter, explode

I already seen how to split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP using

```
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
```

but how to perform the same operation when there is an special symbol after some comma separated values, when finding the special symbol(@), then start a new inner array.

i have a string like this

```
Treatment1,2,500,0%,1000,note1, @ Treatment2,1,2000,250 INR,1750,note2,
```

then i need an array like this

```
Array
(

        [0] => Array
            (
                [treatment] => Treatment1
                [quantity] => 2
                [cost] => 500
                [discount] => 0%
                [discount_type] => INR
                [total] => 1000
                [note] => note1 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [treatment] => Treatment2
                [quantity] => 1
                [cost] => 2000
                [discount] => 250
                [discount_type] => INR
                [total] => 1750
                [note] => note2 
            )
)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything? (Hint: first explode it with a '@' after this explode every part with a ',' :D Try to figure it out!)

Comment: yes i tried using explode like this $myArray[] = explode(',', $cell_value); $myArray[][] = explode('@', $cell_value); , but i get the o/p as Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Treatment1 [1] => 2 [2] => 500 [3] => 0 % [4] => 1000 [5] =>note1 [6] => @ treatment2 [7] => 1 [8] => 2000 [9] => 250 INR [10] => 1750 [11] => [12] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Treatment1,2,500,0 %,1000,note1, [1] =>Treatment2,1,2000,250 INR,1750,, ) )

Comment: Read my hint in the first comment and try it again!

Comment: yes , that was the logic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
str = "your string";
$arr = explode('@', $str);
$newArray = array();
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   $temp = explode(',', $val);
   $newTemp['treatment'] = $temp[0];
   $newTemp['quantity'] = $temp[1];
   $newTemp['cost'] = $temp[2];
   $newTemp['discount'] = $temp[3];
   $newTemp['discount_type'] = "INR";
   $newTemp['total'] = $temp[4];
   $newTemp['note'] = $temp[5];
   $newArray[] = $newTemp;
   $temp = array();
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
$str = "Treatment1,2,500,0%,1000,note1, @ Treatment2,1,2000,250 INR,1750,note2,";

$arr1 = explode("@",$str);

//print_r($arr1);

$finalArr = array();

foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
    $finalArr[] = explode(",",$val);
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

Comment: How up voted this? It's not what OP wants. (Also he has some empty elements in the array)

Comment: What about the keys and the `discount_type` ??

Comment: This have empty element because string have extra comma its not my fault.

Comment: It should be taken care of.

Comment: I don't know all code at scenario how could i measure why this is coming and what's used for.